# Finding the optimal size of $|E|$ for specific inequality

Tags: inequalities

Suppose that we have the following expression $$p^{-2}|E|^6+16p^{-1}|E|^4+p^{2}|E|^2-8p^{-\frac{3}{2}}|E|^5-2|E|^4+8p^{\frac{1}{2}}|E|^3,$$ where $p$ is a prime number.

1. I was wondering is it possible to find some $C>0$ such that if $|E|\geq Cp$ then the above inequality is positive?
2. If the above is not possible then can we find some $C>0$ and $d\in (1,2)$ such that if $|E|\geq Cp^d$ then the above inequality is positive?

I would very thankful for your help because I have tried the first case but I failed. Maybe I am doing something it in a wrong way.

And a more general question: what is method to find this kind of $C$ and $d$?

Comment: crossposted  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4114282/finding-the-optimal-e-for-the-specific-inequality

Comment: Please do not crosspost immediately, or crosspost without linking.

Comment: @WillSawin, Sure! Thanks for this information. I did not know about that. I'll keep it on mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's handle the lowest-order terms, treating $p$ and $|E|$ as degree $1$, using $p\geq 2$

$$p^{-2}|E|^6+16p^{-1}|E|^4+p^{2}|E|^2-8p^{-\frac{3}{2}}|E|^5-2|E|^4+8p^{\frac{1}{2}}|E|^3  $$ $$\geq p^{-2}|E|^6+0+p^{2}|E|^2-4 \sqrt{2} p^{-1}|E|^5-2|E|^4+0 $$
$$ = p^4 ( (|E|/p)^6 - 4\sqrt{2} (|E|/p)^5 - 2 (|E|/p)^4  + (|E|/p)^2 )$$ and we observe that the inner polynomial in $|E|/p$ has leading term positive, so clearly there is some $C$ (the largest real roo) such that this polynomial has positive value of $(|E|/p)>C$.

If wolfram alpha calculated the roots correctly, we can take $C=6$.

The only way to improve this value of $C$ is by shrinking the term $ -4 \sqrt{2} p^{-1}|E|^5$, as the other inequalities we used are sharp for $p$ large.

One general principle for bounds of this type is is "find the right notion of "leading term", then examine the leading term". In this case, we're looking for the term that is largest when $|E|/p$ grows as $p$, potentially grows very large, so we look for terms that have the highest joint degree in $|E|$ and $p$, and, among those, the highest degree in $|E|$.

Comment: Dear Will! Let me tell that is really nice explanation. Because when I read some papers on combinatorics they usually prove this kind of inequality in a converse way, i.e. if $|E|>..$ then some inequality holds. But I have never seen how to find the right cardinality of $E$. Probably I do not have enough experience in this subject yet.

Comment: Can I ask some questions related to your answer, please?

Comment: @ZFR Sure, you can ask.

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "lowest-order terms, treating $p$ and $|E|$ as degree 1? 2) You wrote that "the only way to improve $C$ is shrinking $2-4\sqrt{2}p^{-1}|E|^5$. Where did you get it? Are you sure that you wrote it in a correct way?

Comment: @ZFR What I mean is that we say a term $p^a |E|^b$ has degree $a+b$, and try to get rid of the terms where the degree is not maximal. The idea here is that we might have $p$ very large and $|E|$ only a bit larger than $p$, like $(C+ \epsilon)p$ for $C$ yet to be determined. In that case, the terms where this degree is maximal will dominate all the others. Since we have to focus on those terms in that case, we might as well focus on those terms in every case by getting rid of the remaining terms.

Comment: @ZFR Yes, there was an extraneous $2$. So of the remaining terms, the positive ones we can just ignore as they only help us, not hurt us (and they won't help us much if $p$ is large). For the negative term, we can't ignore it, so we want to bound it by a term of the maximal degree (so that all our terms have the same degree and we can ignore one of the variables, simplifying the problem). We do this by multiplying by a suitable power of $p$, using $p \geq 2$. This is only sharp if $p=2$, but our other inequality was not sharp if $p=2$, so this is a potential locus for improvement.